# PrismJS syntax highlighting is broken due to conflicts with Bulma

Tags: syntax-highlighting, bulma, prismjs

PrismJS syntax highlighting is broken when used together with Bulma.

Both PrismJS and Bulma use the `number` and `tag` classes. So, there is a conflict between PrismJS and Bulma.

[image: PrismJS broken syntax highlighting]

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 workarounds.

### Workaround #1

PrismJS adds `token` class to all highlighted elements including `number` and `tag` unlike Bulma. It allows us to write a more specific CSS rule and resolve conflict with Bulma:

```
.token.number,
.token.tag {
  all: inherit;
  color: #905;
}
```

Just specify the correct color used in your chosen PrismJS theme.

### Workaround #2

Use [Custom Class Prism plugin](https://prismjs.com/plugins/custom-class/).

It allows to prefix all Prism classes (e.g., with `prism-` prefix).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.20.0/components/prism-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.20.0/plugins/autoloader/prism-autoloader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.20.0/plugins/custom-class/prism-custom-class.min.js"></script>
<script>
  Prism.plugins.customClass.prefix('prism-');
</script>
```

So `number` and `tag` become `prism-number` and `prism-tag` so the conflict with Bulma will be resolved.

But you also have to manually prefix classes in Prism CSS style-sheet, e.g.:

```
...    

.prism-token.prism-class-name,
.prism-token.prism-function {
    color: #dd4a68
}

...
```

I don't like this approach due to the need to manually edit Prism theme CSS file and then hosting it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Like Eugene Khyst mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69298861/297257), one way to do it is to use the **Custom Class plugin** for prismjs.
Instead of renaming every prism class you can selectively rename some of the classes. Which should be easier to maintain.

```js
Prism.plugins.customClass.map({
    number: 'prism-number',
    tag: 'prism-tag'
});
```

This will rename only the number and tag classes.